# when search features works it causes error on nesting routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement a search with on an index page.
However it's affecting the nested route of a single entry when I add the code. [I tried gems, using elsif, and anything else I could think of].

For context, I'm using books belongs to authors scenario.

I'd like to implement this:

```
@comicbooks = Comicbook.search(params[:search])
```

into here:

```
 def index

@comicbooks = @comicbooks.filter_by_name(params[:name]) 
 if params[:person_id]
      person = Person.find_by(id: params[:person_id])
      @comicbooks = person.comicbooks

    else
      @comicbooks = Comicbook.all
    end
  end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Comicbook < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :squad
  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :person }

def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name Like ?', "%#{:search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end

  def person_attributes=(args)
    self.person = Person.find_or_create_by(args)
  end

  def squad_attributes=(args)
    self.squad = Squad.find_or_create_by(args)
  end
end
```

Here is the search form on the view

```
 <%= form_tag comicbooks_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" , :name => nil %>
    <% end %>
```

Whats the best way to implement search without throwing off the other routes? I've tried many gems, but they've complicated things more than I can understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Rails version is it?

Comment: I think this might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL5DTg2WggQ&t=53s

Answer (score 0):

You can use scope in your model and chain in your controller

Model:

```
 scope :search, -> (search) do
    return if search.blank?
    where('name Like ?', "%#{:search}%")
  end
```

Controller:

```
@comicbooks = Comicbook.filter_by_name(params[:name]).search(params[:search])
```

Comment: thank you for the tip. that give this error - `undefined method `filter_by_name' for nil:NilClass`

`def index
    
    @comicbooks = @comicbooks.filter_by_name(params[:name]).search(params[:search])
    # search doesn't work yet.
    if params[:person_id]
      # This is the nested route, /person/:author_id/comicbooks`

Comment: someone gave a tip and said "you can chain your scope method to the other active record methods
like ```person.comicbooks.filter_by_name(...)```

would that then be 

```@comicbooks = @comicbooks.person.filter_by_name(params[:name]).search(params[:search])```

Comment: @user3251999 I had updated the answer, you should use your model to chain.